# Sign an S/MIME message with openssl or pure node.js

Tags: node.js, openssl, digital-signature, pkcs#7, smime

I received `.pem`, `.cer`, `.p12` files and related passPhrase for these from  from Bank tech team .

I should sign a string like this:

```
8ad281ad-1fdf-4ef9-a308-31388b617c3c-b6767a8a-dbc7-4be0-86ff-d27b47ed0df3
```

to generate a valid signed-data like this:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed-data; name="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

MIIHnQYJKoZIhvcNAQ...cQfLnkhnZGwg7d
```

I've tried using `openssl` commands like this:

```
openssl smime -sign -nosigs -in msg.txt -out out.txt -passin pass:SOMEPASS -signer certificate.pem
```

But it does not generate like what I mentioned above.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/x-pkcs7-signature"; micalg="sha-256"; boundary="----1F579F2DD2078A7D3BE2F25D30C33EFC"

This is an S/MIME signed message

------1F579F2DD2078A7D3BE2F25D30C33EFC
8ad281ad-1fdf-4ef9-a308-31388b617c3c-b6767a8a-dbc7-4be0-86ff-d27b47ed0df3
------1F579F2DD2078A7D3BE2F25D30C33EFC
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-signature; name="smime.p7s"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7s"

MIIHUAYJKoZIhvcNAQc...Nwr/k3x
EkGgGg==

------1F579F2DD2078A7D3BE2F25D30C33EFC--
```

Also tried this:

```
openssl smime -encrypt -nosigs -in msg.txt -out out.txt -passin pass:SOMEPASS  certificate.pem
```

and I receive this which is clearly different `smime-type` in header:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data; name="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

MIIBewYJKoZIhvc...
```

And I've tried several NodeJs packages to do this sign in pure node but as I don't know much about this field, can not get result.

I get results with PHP sample code I received from bank, here is sample:

```
openssl_pkcs7_sign(realpath("msg.txt"), realpath("signed.txt"), "file://C:/myCert/certificate.pem",
    array("file://C:/myCert/certificate.pem", "SOMEPASS"),
    array(),PKCS7_NOSIGS
);
```